# Angular HttpClient - request not executed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I cant get the HttpClient request to be fired. Probably it is some importing or providing issue, but can't find where it is.
The API does work, but never gets called.

As for the environment/versions:

- Angular: 15.1.2 Angular
- CLI: 15.1.3
- Node: 16.14.2
- Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
- OS: win32 x64

The layout is:
I have a main landing page, hosting several *widgets* which is a quick look into the targeted content. Each *widgets* has its own component.
Services, providing the data for the *widgets* and provided in `root` and they expose an Observable to which each component subscribes to.

**app.module.ts**

```
const pipes = [
  SignUpFormTextPipe,
  StageFormatTextPipe,
  StageTypeTextPipe,
  TeamSizeTextPipe,
  TournamentStatusTextPipe,
];

const providers = [HttpClientModule];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...components, ...pipes],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [...pipes, ...providers],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

**The service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Tournament } from '../models/tournament/tournament';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, take, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { TournamentsResponse } from '../models/api-responses/tournament/tournaments-response';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TournamentService {
  private baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5077/api/tournamens';

  initialTournaments: Tournament[] = [];
  private tournaments = new BehaviorSubject<Tournament[]>(
    this.initialTournaments
  );

  public tournaments$ = this.tournaments.asObservable();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getTournaments(): Observable<TournamentsResponse> {
    console.log('test 123'); // this is fired

    return this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        console.log(resp); // this ain't fired

        this.tournaments.next(resp.tournaments);

        return resp;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

**One of the components subscribing to it:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { Tournament } from 'src/app/models/tournament/tournament';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/services/common/notification.service';
import { TournamentService } from 'src/app/services/tournament.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upcoming-tourneys',
  templateUrl: './upcoming-tourneys.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upcoming-tourneys.component.css'],
})
export class UpcomingTourneysComponent implements OnInit {
  private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  upcomingTournaments$: Observable<Tournament[]> =
    this.tournamentService.tournaments$;

  constructor(
    private tournamentService: TournamentService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.tournamentService); // this gets fired and logged properly

    this.tournamentService
      .getTournaments()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          console.log(resp); // this ain't get fired
        },
        error: (resp) => {
          this.notificationService.showError(resp);
        },
      });
  }
}
```

**and the related components HTML**:

```
test if component is rendered
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="upcomingTournaments$ | async as upcomingTournaments">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" routerLink="/tournaments">
      Upcoming tournaments
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <div *ngFor="let tourney of upcomingTournaments">
         ... content...
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This most probably is a very vague error since I have the same pattern in another working app. I got some initial feedback that it is most probably an error on the imports, but intelisense/linter doesn't give the hint.

[image]
[image]

*** **UPDATE 1** ***
I have altered the service as suggested below by @flo to use `lastValueFrom(...)`.
Unfortunately HTTP call still not fired. :(

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TournamentService {
  private baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5077/api/tournamens';

  initialTournaments: Tournament[] = [];
  private tournamentsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Tournament[]>(
    this.initialTournaments
  );

  public tournaments$ = this.tournamentsSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getTournaments() {
    const result = lastValueFrom(
      this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl)
    ).then((resp) => {
      this.tournamentsSubject.next(resp.tournaments);
    });
  }
}
```

In the component typescript file:

```
export class UpcomingTourneysComponent implements OnInit {
  upcomingTournaments$: Observable<Tournament[]> =
    this.tournamentService.tournaments$;

  constructor(private tournamentService: TournamentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tournamentService.getTournaments();
  }
}
```

In the component template:

```
test if component is rendered
{{ upcomingTournaments$ | async }}
<div
  class="container-fluid"
  *ngIf="upcomingTournaments$ | async as upcomingTournaments"
>
....
```

*** **UPDATE 2** ***
Since it does not seems to work, I tried to remove all observables from the story and I have updated the service call as below.. Yet still no get call fired :*

The service:

```
  public getTournaments(): Observable<TournamentsResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl);
  }
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const response = this.tournamentService.getTournaments().subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
        console.log({ what: 'next call within service subscribe', resp }); // logs an ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
      },
    });
    console.log({ what: 'upcomingTourneysInit', response }); // here Response is SafeSubscriber
  }
```

Comment: `providers: [...pipes, ...providers],` seems incorrect because you provide HttpClientModule to providers.

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov Apologies, but I am unsure if I get what you mean. Or rather what the correct approach would be. I have declared an array, listing each providers and provide it to NgModule declaration

Comment: I mean you already provided HttpClientModule in `imports` array of your NgModule. Then you are extracting `...providers` into providers array of NgModule. But in `const providers` you have HttpClientModule (it is module and not a provider) maybe this causes issue

Comment: still unsure what you suggest :(
Anyway, I have tested to change providers declaration to `const providers = [HttpClient];`.
Also I have tested to omit providers from NgModule initialization.
None of these fixed the mistake

Comment: do you see request to http://localhost:5077/api/tournamens in Network tab of devtools?

Comment: no, the whole http call is not fired. The API works, of that I am sure.

Comment: httpClient return an **Observable** not a promise, so your updated code is wrong

Comment: @Eliseo lastValueFrom returns a Promise, not an Observable though

Comment: ::glups:: sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not properly assigning a value to your baseUrl in the service.
The service now has:

```
private baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5077/api/tournamens';
```

But that does not assign the value of your API url, rather it's marking it as its type.

The correct code should be:

```
private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:5077/api/tournamens';
```

Also, consider returning an Observable from your service and subscribing in your template using the async pipe to avoid having to handle subscriptions manually.

Comment: thank you! I was so sure this is some dumb mistake... Now the http call is fired. Though still denied due to CORS error, which I dont quite get in local environment, but thats a different issue.

and yeah, I wanted initially as well to subscribe via the async pipe from the template.  Seems a much better approach vs managing the unsubscribscription

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `tap` in your service. Read the docs:

> Tap into the Observable
> The getHeros() method taps into the flow of observable values and sends a message, using the log() method, to the message area at the bottom of the page.

> The RxJS tap() operator enables this ability by looking at the observable values, doing something with those values, and passing them along. The tap() callback doesn't access the values themselves.

Tap has **no access to the data itself**

[Link](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable) to docs

You can use the function `toPrimose` (but it's deprecated - so use `lastValueFrom`) to get the data from the http.

This should be the right way:

```
 public getTournaments(): Observable<TournamentsResponse> {
    console.log('test 123'); // this is fired
    const result = lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl));

    this.tournaments.next(result.tournaments);      
);
```

And then you need subscribe to the `tournaments$` in your app.

```
export class UpcomingTourneysComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  upcomingTournaments!: any;
  tournamentSub!: Subscription;

  constructor(private tournamentService: TournamentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tournamentSub = this.tournamentService.tournaments$.subscribe(data => {
      upcomingTournaments = data;
    })
    this.tournamentService.getTournaments();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tournamentSub.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

This will return a current result.

Comment: wouldn't pushing the next value of an observable satisfy the definition of 
`looking at the observable values, doing something with those values, and passing them along` ?
This however didn't solve the mistake either. 
Maybe I  miss how to call this method? As its a promise, I cannot subscribe to it. Simply calling it did not solve. Resulted in
`main.ts:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`

Comment: I have removed the tap (I forgot, my mistake). The corrected code should be do what you need. The HTTP request will fire, will update the tounaments and all subscribers will be get the data

Comment: the code sample has syntax error. 
how/where do you call this method now in the service?

Comment: Today is not my day. Now the code should be correct. You can call simple the method and your Observable will be updated (`tournaments$`). And you need to subscribe this Observable in your app, not more the `getTournaments()` method. This method you only need to call.

Comment: `const result = lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl));` this will end up as a `Promise` on which I could not chain the `result.tournaments`. 
I have chained a `.then` call afterwards (see update 1) to get access to the response itself. Though the HTTP client call still not fired..

Comment: I wrote you need to subscribe to the tournaments$. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have subscribed in the template with `{{ upcomingTournaments$ | async }}`
Anyway, I have tested your suggestion (to subscribe from the typescript file instead), still, it doesn't fire.
` public getTournaments() {
    const result = lastValueFrom(
      this.httpClient.get<TournamentsResponse>(this.baseUrl)
    ).then((resp) => {
      this.tournamentsSubject.next(resp.tournaments);
    });
  }`

Comment: ts part>
  `ngOnInit() {
    this.tournamentSub = this.tournamentService.tournaments$.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.tournaments = data;
      }
    );
    this.tournamentService.getTournaments();
  }`